# Bach Partita II Allemande, Practice Advice

Tags: practice, violin

I am a student on the violin for about 3 years now, and currently practicing Bach's Partita II Allemande.
I would like to ask for some practice advice on how to play the chord.

[image]

How do you practice this?

My question is how to practice an arpeggio in general. I have never played them, so I do not know how to practice efficiently. At the moment it just sounds like a mess, when I attempt to play it. So how should I practice? First every note by itself, trying to play faster and faster?

Comment: Looks to me like an arpeggio, played high to low, written in a sort of graphic way. If possible, all notes should 'let ring' - hold on to all for the beat and a half shown.

Comment: It would help more to know where in the piece it occurs, and surrounding bars shown, too.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your reply. It is actually played low to high. You can listen to the partita here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_EeQ2snbXY The arpeggio occurs the first time at around 1:38. My question is how to practice an arpeggio in general. Do I play every note for itself and just keep getting faster and faster, or how do I approach this?

Comment: Welcome! I have a lot of advice about the Allemande in general, and could think of a lot of things to say about that chord, but it would help if you could narrow  the question somewhat, more than “everything you can think about this chord.“ What kind of practice? What kind of issues? Intonation? Bow speed over the course of the chord? How fast to roll? Fingering?

Comment: I am asking mainly for a practice advice on these arpeggios over all. I have never played them, so I do not know how to practice efficiently. At the moment it just sounds like a mess, when I attempt to play it. So how should I practice? First every note by itself, trying to play faster and faster?

Comment: @AndyBonner - is that arp. around 1:40 in the recording?

Comment: @Tim yup, 1:39 or so. Working on an answer.

Comment: @AndyBonner - then to be intuitive, the dots ought to have been written with lowest first! Or, properly, with a squiggle.

Comment: @Tim They're written the way they are because to write them lowest first would make the dotted part of the note too problematic. Also, this is not a "chord" per se, it's four voices, so an arpeggio mark would be inappropriate.

Comment: @Aaron - sounds like an arp. to me, in the included video. Point taken about the dotted notes, though.

Comment: @Tim It's not fully arpeggiated; it's played as two double-stops. An arpeggio mark would imply each note individually. My mistake about it being four voices, though.

Comment: @Tim it's written that way because notes sharing stems hadn't yet caught on in those days, and if you reverse the horizontal order then the stems bump into the note heads of the higher notes.

Comment: @Aaron "it's played as two double-stops": that's one way it's played.  It's not the only way.

Comment: @phoog I was referring to the recording.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for clarifying.  I hadn't listened to the recording and I thought you were speaking generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the challenge you're facing is simply how to play four-note chords on violin; I'll answer focusing on that.

This single note stands in for a lot of issues and challenges. It's not just an "arpeggio" per se; it's a genuine four-note chord. But the violin is not inherently a chordal instrument, like an organ or lute; it was born to play melodic lines (including in "consort," like a string quartet, using several instruments to make a harmony). But Bach's solo violin sonatas and partitas contain a whole lot of chords. Much, much has been said about these works as "polyphonic" violin music, including a lot of talk about how exactly they should be played. Some of that talk has been more outlandish and far-fetched, and some is more reasonable. The immediate "problem" is that the violin's bridge is curved, so you can't play four strings all at the same time. Or can you? In the 1960s some folks thought that surely Bach wanted these chords to be "chordal," and invented bows with giant curves so that you could wrap the hair around all four strings, some with levers so you could stretch the hair back to "normal" tension in between chords.*

But the fact is, Bach didn't really make the violin's abilities his foremost consideration. He wasn't ignorant of how the violin "prefers" to behave, but some of his contrapuntal and fugal writing is almost "idealized," as if it would be "better" played on a more chordal instrument like an organ. And in fact, he often rewrote his own compositions for one instrument into a version for another; he turned some of his violin concertos into harpsichord concertos, and he made lute versions of several of these violin sonatas and partitas. Often these contain even more polyphony, and it can be instructive as a violinist to listen to them and hear the "missing" chords, or how the existing chords are played on an instrument that is more at home with them.

Meanwhile, these violin sonatas and partitas have been an important part of violin canon for a long time, and since this Allemande has only one four-note chord (and only a couple of other double-stops), it's often the movement that students are assigned to learn first. (By the way, if your teacher approves, I like to use some of Telemann's solo violin "fantasias" to learn some of the same skills, but on shorter and less-challenging pieces.)

No, you can't hope to sustain all four pitches for a beat and a half at a tempo that even at the very most daringly (historically?) fast is no more than ca 70 bpm. And that's not the point. As modern players we're used to a very literal understanding of note duration and of double stops—if somebody writes a four-beat double stop of two pitches, we hold ourselves responsible to crank out exactly 3.999999+ beats of exactly both pitches. But this is not really a baroque attitude. First of all, baroque practice does not assume "sustain" the way we do, in which a whole note is, by default, four full beats of one homogeneous volume. Instead, *by default* baroque performance "shapes" notes with crescendo or decrescendo, and if the note happens to fade out a bit before its time, it's not a crime <sub>(unless it was meant to connect seamlessly to another note, as determined by voice leading)</sub>. Secondly, there's a recognition that "the music" is more than what's being produced by the violin. For instance, in this line from the G minor sonata,

[image]

... the listener can imagine a "bass line" connecting the bottom notes, G, A, D, G. Throughout all six works (and works by other contemporaries, like Telemann or Walther), there are lots of moments in which the musical ideal has to be "imaginary," while the violin simply marks the beginnings of notes and leaves it to the hearer to imagine their "sustain."

All that to say: Yeah, you should roll the bow across all four strings. Now, how long do you spend on each string? That's a ripe field for personal interpretation. It could vary with the mood of the piece and the significance of the chord. Do you play them as four separate notes? Play them as if it's a pair of two-note double stops? Do you sustain the top note by itself after rolling, or the top two notes? Let's check a few performances:

Here's the Hilary Hahn recording you started with: She does almost exactly "two plus two," spending a split second on the D string by itself:

Hilary Hahn's recording is a pretty significant one; although she is definitely not using a historically-informed baroque approach, she tempers some of the high-romantic approaches of others like Perlman.

But the earlier generation was not all Brahmsian; Henryk Szeryng's Allemande is quite unsentimental, almost businesslike. He simply plows straight through the chord, sustaining the top double stop:

Let's try some performers who *are* trying to let what we know about historical baroque performance inform their approach. Rachel Barton Pine plays three separate notes topped with a bit of double-stop:

(By the way: you *must* take a detour to watch her masterclass on this movement. Besides being a great performer, she's always been a brilliant pedagogist.)

I'm not able to find my favorite baroque violin recording, John Holloway's, on Youtube, but you can find it [on Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/12aPPugXaLY2W43H4lL6Mo) or other services like Apple or Amazon music. He goes a step further, rolls right across the chord, and sustains only the topmost pitch.

Let's take a second, also, to see how it might be interpreted on a totally different instrument. This partita isn't one of the ones for which we have a lute arrangement by Bach himself, but Miguel Rincón gives us a pretty good idea what it might be like:

... and he has the liberty to mix it up a bit, taking the notes out of order!

---

Now, that's all about how to roll the chord. There are other practical considerations here too.

- Bow *use*, or distribution, or bow speed. Sometimes when students approach a rolled chord they have trouble separating the idea of rolling rapidly *across* the strings from using up lots of bow by moving rapidly frog-to-tip. You can fight this by practicing rolling "in place." Simply place the bow, stationary, on G string, and roll to E and back. Keep this up and start adding a bit of lateral motion. Vary the amount of bow you "use up," all the way to using an entire bow in a single second. Finally, use this control to intentionally use more or less bow speed (and pressure!) to have a good tone at all times. If your Allemande tempo is on the faster side you shouldn't have to worry much about saving bow anyway, but if you have a very slow tempo for learning (or are being coached into a lugubrious Romantic-soliloquy Adagio, or a sustained forte on this note), then you might to use no more than the bottom quarter of the bow on the roll and save the rest for the "sustain." This is made more challenging since the chord is preceded by a long downbow slur and then a single short upbow note, so save bow on the slur (and avoid a big ritardando!), and spend it on the upbow (including lifting off the string and replacing near the frog if necessary). (But personally I'd make less of a big deal out of this half cadence anyway, with no big *Also-Sprach-Zarathustra*-style rit or swell or flourish or sustain—just cadence and get on with it!)
- Intonation: It won't matter what you do with the bow if the left hand pitches aren't in tune. Practice the chord as a set of double stops: D and A string, A and E string, etc. It's especially challenging since the G and D string use the same finger. If this fifth seems out of tune, there are a few things you can check:

  - Make darn sure the strings themselves are perfectly in tune
  - Make sure you're pressing your finger onto both strings equally. Are they both meeting the fingerboard securely?
  - Experiment with the angle of your finger. Is the part that touches the D string "farther back" than the G string? Does it help if you come at the string more from the side, or from behind? Even if you need to alter your normal left hand posture, you might do so just for this note.

---

Since the question asks for practical advice about how to practice this chord, I'll add some about that.

> I am asking mainly for a practice advice on these arpeggios over all. I have never played them, so I do not know how to practice efficiently. At the moment it just sounds like a mess, when I attempt to play it. So how should I practice? First every note by itself, trying to play faster and faster?

Note, there's already been some confusion in the comments section about the word "arpeggio," so let's not use that. This is a "chord"; even if you roll across it—even if each of the four notes is played totally on its own as Holloway does—it's one "thing." And, just to make sure we're clear, it happens all in one bow direction. Now, you can certainly practice it in other ways, like as four separate bows, just to hear them well. But make sure you separate left-hand and right-hand concerns.

The left hand's job is simply to supply the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd fingers to make these notes happen. Fortunately, the preceding note is an open D, so they're free to get ready. In fact, although you can't put down the 1st finger while playing that D, you can put the 2nd and 3rd on the C# and A a few milliseconds in advance. See advice above about making sure the fingers are well placed. You can practice it as a pizzicato strum to take all bow concerns out of the picture, or as a series of three double stops.

Then, the right hand's job is to roll across the strings; this is where the rest of this answer above comes into play, deciding how quickly to roll, and the specific advice immediately above about bow usage. To practice the bowing, you might take your fingers off the strings entirely and just practice rolling across all four open strings a few times, thinking about the timing and how it affects your bow usage.

All four notes don't have to be handled equally; I'd advise thinking of the top note as the melody (connecting from the G#), and giving it prominence. Second most important might be the bass note as it goes from D to A. The middle two strings are just there to fill things out, and needn't get as much bow speed or weight as the outer ones.

---

* Also, you totally can play four notes simultaneously any old time—they just have to be loud and short.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very insightful!

Comment: "and he made lute versions of several of these violin sonatas and partitas": there's also one for solo organ and orchestra.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that you put down all fingers for the left hand for a chord, then play the strings with the bow in some usually arpeggiated manner.  Essentially "do like a guitar" regarding the left hand, just that you don't get the benefit of frets.  Sometimes this results in having to place a finger on two strings, partly even at different positions.  Sometimes you need to juggle your fingers to get everything crammed into one "chord" with reasonably good intonation ("instantaneous" correction by auditory feedback doesn't really work with multiple fingers at once).

While the right hand has to employ considerable leeway into breaking a chord's sounding up, if you'd do the same with the left hand, it messes up the "chord" character a lot more.  So you often have to figure out a position where all notes can be fingered at once.

Another thing worth noting is that if Bach puts stems in different directions, this means using different strings *even* for the same note, sort of sequential polyphony.  Again, one wants to put down all fingers at once and then just change strings around.  The Prelude of Partita 3 has several three-string passages in that manner, the Chaconne of Partita 2 also has a few such passages, with the last or penultimate page containing a number of slurred two-string passages.

Again, it probably helps thinking more like a guitarist (or actually lutenist) for getting the hang of how to do this.  Bluegrass shuffle bowing is actually quite related.